# View of users based on multiple term references

Tags: views

I am trying to show a list of users based on their taxonomy terms, e.g 'show all users tagged with term 'ms office' for vocabulary 'software' or term 'europe' for 'region' or 'marketing' for 'department'.

I have 3 vocabularies set up and 3 user fields referencing them. Using contextual filters,  I would imagine it would be a matter of adding 3 filters (each vocabulary reference), then providing a default value taxonomy term id from URL. This seems to work for only one filter, the moment I add a second one stops showing anything. What am I doing wrong? I know how to do this for content, using a single contextual filter on content:has taxonomy term id and providing a default value taxonomy term id from URL, but there is not such option for filtering users.

Edit: so the issue seems to be that contextual filters are being combined to AND by default, and I would need to show users of software tid 80 OR region tid 80 etc.

Edit: this is the view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'users_by_taxonomy_term_test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Users by taxonomy term test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Users by taxonomy term';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: User: Applications (field_user_applications) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid'] ['id'] = 'field_user_applications_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']   ['table'] = 'field_data_field_user_applications';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']['field'] = 'field_user_applications_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'taxonomy_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_user_applications_tid']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: User: Region (field_region) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['id'] = 'field_region_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_region';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['field'] = 'field_region_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_region_tid']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: User: Department (field_department) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['id'] = 'field_department_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_department';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['field'] = 'field_department_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_department_tid']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'users-by-taxonomy-term/%/%/%';
```

Comment: In contextual filter Choose option 'Display all results for the specified field' for all three filter and check again.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it; it only picks up results from whichever filter is first on the list. I need to be able to show users from all 3 vocabularies...

Comment: In my case It will filter all of three filter if present. Can you export code here?

Comment: I edited the question to include the view code. Thanks

Comment: There is no problem in your view. May be you are passing wrong argument via URL.It must be first argument is tid of  user_applications term referance,  second argument is tid of region term referance, third argument is tid of department term referance. Order of argument must be this for above view.

Comment: I thought of that, but it doesn't do it. When I go to users-by-taxonomy-term/23 it shows me users with application tid 23 fine, but if I go to users-by-taxonomy-term/23/80 it shows nothing. And if I rearrange filters to show region term as 1st argument and go to users-by-taxonomy-term/80, shows users for that region, but at users-by-taxonomy-term/80/23 shows nothing. I'm not sure what I am missing here...

Comment: It means there is not any user that belongs to both term ID. Edit any user and assign both term.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I completely ignored it could be that. So then how can I get the view to return users that have application tid 23, users that have region tid 80, etc. but not matching both?

Comment: Edit your question for this new requirement.